# apache error log for rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

i am getting following error in apache log

File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/script/products, referer: http://localhost/script/products/category/product-123.html whenever following url localhost/script/products/category/product-123.html is parsed through this rewrite rule RewriteRule ^products/([~A-Za-z0-9-"]+)/([~A-Za-z0-9-".]+).html$ index.php?page_type=products&prod=$2 [L].

The script and rule is working fine but i am getting that error in apache error log.
I have activated RewriteLog, but nothing is showing up in the rewrite.log file. Its empty.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/script/products/([~A-Za-z0-9-"]+)/([~A-Za-z0-9-".]+).html$ index.php?page_type=products&prod=$2 [L]
```